# Pyspark create map type colum from a string column

Tags: dictionary, pyspark

Hi I have a table with a column that is something like this:-

VER:some_ver DLL:some_dll as:bcd,2.sc4 OR:SCT SG:3 SLC:13

From this row of data,

The output should be a maptype column:

| Data | MapColumn |
| --- | --- |
| VER:some_ver DLL:some_dll as:bcd,2.sc4 OR:SCT SG:3 SLC:13 | {"VER": "65010000", "DLL":"some_dll", "as":"bcd,2.sc4", "OR":"SCT", "SG":"3", "SLC":"13"} |

I tried using explode but I am getting just one row of each key,value pair

```
df= df.withColumn("map_col", f.explode(f.split(f.col("data")," ")))\
                         .withColumn("key", f.trim(f.split(f.col("data"),":").getItem(0)))\
                         .withColumn("value", f.trim(f.split(f.col("data"),":").getItem(1)))\
                         .withColumn("map_col", f.create_map(f.col("key"),f.col("value")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have to be certain that:

1. `':'` separates the key/value pair and it doesn't show up anywhere else
2. single space separates the entries and it doesn't show up anywhere else

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Column

_data = [
    ('VER:some_ver DLL:some_dll as:bcd,2.sc4 OR:SCT SG:3 SLC:13',),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(_data, ['data', ])


def parse_struct(x: Column) -> Column:
    inner_split = F.split(x, pattern=':')
    return F.struct(inner_split.getItem(0), inner_split.getItem(1))


split = F.split('data', pattern='\s').alias('split')
map_col = F.map_from_entries(F.transform(split, parse_struct))
df2 = df.withColumn('map_column', map_col)
df2.select('map_column').show(10, False)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|map_column                                                                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{VER -> some_ver, DLL -> some_dll, as -> bcd,2.sc4, OR -> SCT, SG -> 3, SLC -> 13}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about map_from_entries. That is one handy function

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if there is a space right after a ':' then how would you go about it, eg. VER: some_ver. It could be possible that some key values have that space after a ':'

Comment: `pattern` can be a Java regular expression, so the 2 splits can be adjusted